# Creating a sharepoint online site with C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, c-sharp

Hi I've succeeded creating document libraries and folders but I'm having trouble creating a (communication) site in SharePoint online.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please elaborate your problem in more words and also provide code that you tried so far so people can understand your problem in more better way to help you out!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the
// server running SharePoint.
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl");

WebCreationInformation creation = new WebCreationInformation();
creation.Url = "web1";
creation.Title = "Hello web1";
Web newWeb = context.Web.Webs.Add(creation);

// Retrieve the new web information.
context.Load(newWeb, w => w.Title);
context.ExecuteQuery();

label1.Text = newWeb.Title;
```

source: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to create communication and modern team site in modern SharePoint online is using PnP PowerShell command, its very sample and user friendly:

**Below is the PnP PowerShell command to create communication site in SharePoint online:**

```
New-PnPSite -Type CommunicationSite -Title Contoso -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso -SiteDesign Showcase
```

Notes:

SiteDesign is enum type, we can pass any of the below:

- Topic
- Showcase
- Blank

For more details please refer the below Microsoft article:

[New-PnPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Prerequisites to execute the PnP PowerShell:**

In order to execute the PnP PowerShell command, we need to install the "PnP PowerShell", please refer the below article to install PnP PowerShell:

[Office 365: Getting started with SharePoint PnP PowerShell – installation](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/office365-sharepoint-pnp-powershell-installation/)

Nevertheless, we can create communication site using C# coding as well, Microsoft has provided all the options we need.

**C# coding to create communication site:**

```
// Let's use the CreateSiteAsync extension method of PnP CSOM Core
// to create the "modern" team site

var targetTenantUrl = "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/";

using (var context = new ClientContext(targetTenantUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential("[Name-of-Your-Credentials]");

    // Create new "modern" communication site at the url https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/mymoderncommunicationsite
    var communicationContext = await context.CreateSiteAsync(new CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation {
        Title = "title", // Mandatory
        Description = "description", // Mandatory
        Lcid = 1033, // Mandatory
        AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers = false, // Optional
        Classification = "classification", // Optional
        SiteDesign = CommunicationSiteDesign.Topic, // Mandatory
        Url = "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/mymoderncommunicationsite", // Mandatory
    });
    communicationContext.Load(communicationContext.Web, w => w.Url);
    communicationContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    Console.WriteLine(communicationContext.Web.Url);
}
```

For more details, please refer the below article:

[Provisioning "modern" team sites programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-provisioning-sites)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PNP CSOM component to help you to achieve that.

Link to Nuget PnP CSOM Core component - [link to Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline)

```
var targetTenantUrl = "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/";

using (var context = new ClientContext(targetTenantUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential("[Name-of-Your-Credentials]");

    // Create new "modern" communication site at the url https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/mymoderncommunicationsite
    var communicationContext = await context.CreateSiteAsync(new CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation {
        Title = "title", // Mandatory
        Description = "description", // Mandatory
        Lcid = 1033, // Mandatory
        AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers = false, // Optional
        Classification = "classification", // Optional
        SiteDesign = CommunicationSiteDesign.Topic, // Mandatory
        Url = "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/mymoderncommunicationsite", // Mandatory
    });
    communicationContext.Load(communicationContext.Web, w => w.Url);
    communicationContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    Console.WriteLine(communicationContext.Web.Url);
}
```

Note that the property SiteDesign "CommunicationSiteDesign" could be

- CommunicationSiteDesign.Topic
- CommunicationSiteDesign.Showcase
- CommunicationSiteDesign.Blank

[More information here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-provisioning-sites)